# Controlling different subdomains from one main domain

Tags: php

I am having the following code with which I want to list all the items in my folder.

```
$directory  = "../img"; 
$images = scandir($directory);
$ignore = Array(".", "..");
$count=1;
echo "<table border=0 style='float:left;'>";
foreach($images as $dispimage){
    if(!in_array($dispimage, $ignore)){
    echo "<tr id='del$count'><td>$count</td><td style='width:300px;'><a href='$directory/$dispimage' target='_blank'>../img/$dispimage</a></td><td><input type='button' style='padding:0;height:17px;' id='delete$count' value='Delete' onclick='deleteFile(\"$dispimage\",$count,\"$directory\");'></td></tr>";
    $count++;
    }
}
```

This code is working properly. I am currently making a CMS for 3 different websites (subdomains) and would like to control everything from the main domain (CMS). In which way I can list `$directory  = "../img"` to be `$directory  = "mysubdomain/img"` and manipulate data in it.

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you ask.

Comment: let say I am having www.mysite.com and I am listing the items of the img folder like $directory  = "../img"; 
$images = scandir($directory); in which way can I list the items from the img folder of my subdomain subdomain.mysite.com, I have tried with $directory  = "subdomain.mysite.com/img"; 
$images = scandir($directory); but it is not working

Comment: are the subdomains fixed?

Comment: are your images organized based on your subdomains?

Comment: You are currently trying around without understanding the concept of a 'domain'. I suggest you start reading about "virtual hosts" and make some tries yourself, then things will become more clear to you.

Comment: Dear Arkascha, if you have no better suggestions you are of no help whether I need to read about it or not

Answer (score 0):

In order to list all files in all img/ directories on all subdomains you will need to scandir them all with this script.

The path to the first folder is "../img/" as you have in this code. This could represent the script being in:

```
/home/user/public_html/scripts/
```

and the images folder being in:

```
/home/user/public_html/img/
```

BUt we don't know where your domains are. If you have two subdomains alpha and beta, the img/ folder may be at these locations:

```
/home/user/public_html/alpha/img/
/home/user/public_html/beta/img/
```

If that's the case then you need to run two more scandirs:

```
scandir('../alpha/img/');
scandir('../beta/img/');
```

Or change you directory to:

```
$directory  = "../img";
/* save result */
$directory  = "../alpha/img"; 
/* save result */
$directory  = "../beta/img"; 
/* save result */
/* Show all three results somehow to user */
```

At least you will have to change alpha and beta to the subdirectory names of the subdomain. At most you will have to find the path to the files on the server.